# How to Highlight Menu Item on MouseOver in WPF

Tags: wpf

I have a Menu Item that won't change its background when I put my mouse over it.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DropItemStyle" TargetType="MenuItem">
        <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="#FF101315" Height="40" Width="250" Margin="-1,-1,0,0">
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Height="15" Width="15" Margin="12,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            <Label Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" FontFamily="Segoe UI Semibold" FontSize="14" Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-12,-1,0,0" />
            <Image Source="Images/icon_right.png" Visibility="{Binding HasItems, Converter={StaticResource btv}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />

            <DockPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1A1D1F" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DockPanel.Style>
        </DockPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>

<MenuItem Header="Logout" Template="{StaticResource DropItemStyle}" Icon="Images/logoutIcon.png" Click="logoutButtonClick" />
```

Please edit this if there is any mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting Background="#FF101315" on the DockPanel has a greater priority than the trigger's setter. Move it to the Style instead:

```
<DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Width="250" Margin="-1,-1,0,0">

<!-- Skipped for readability -->

            <Style TargetType="DockPanel">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF101315"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF1A1D1F" />
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
```